# Spring 4 and EJB3

Tags: ejb, java-ee-7, spring-4

I want to separate frontend and backend into two different JVMs. I know EJB3 is for that purpose. Nevertheless I have not found documentation and examples to implement it using Spring 4.

Could you provide an example about (define a EJB and its implementation, expose it the backend, consume it in frontend)? Does it has something to do with @Stateless, @Remote, @Local?

An example of service to publish as EJB could be the following:

```
public interface {
   int mult(int a, int b);
}

public class CalcServiceImpl implements CalcService {
   @Override
   public int mult(int a, int b) { return a*b; }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-intro.htm#GIJSZ

Comment: Thank you. Please, could you provide more info and an example about how to do it in Spring 4?